# Program design - update global variable value

Tags: python, function, design-patterns

Suppose I have a global variable pi=3.14 in a script. In most cases, the pi is used as 3.14 in functions and classes in the script. However, the user might need to change the value sometimes. Can the user change the value of pi in the script without modifying the script?
(The user don't want to pass the pi to the function as argument.)

For example, the user defines his own pi in another script or Jupyter notebook, and import the relevant functions and classes. Then, the functions and classes will use the new pi. From a software design perspective, is there a good way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Can the user change the value" – yes, it's just another variable. "From a software design perspective, is there a good way to do that?" No, changing globals is exactly the kind of situation that makes globals bad. If you want good software design, *do not* use mutable globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's a bad practice to set globals into the python `builtins` if this is not completely necessary.

Here's what I would have done:

```py
# foo_module.constants.py


class Constants:
    # set them as class variables
    pi: float = 3.14
    phi: float = 1.61
```

your functions and classes:

```py
# foo_module.my_application

from .constants import Constants


def circle_area(r):
    return Constants.pi * (r ** 2)


class Circumfator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pi = Constants.pi

    def get_circumference(self, r):
        return 2 * r * self.pi
```

Users perceptive:

```py
from foo_package.my_application import *


circle_area(10)  # returns 314.0
Circumfator().get_circumference(50)  # returns 314.0

# user changes pi
Constants.pi = 1

circle_area(10)  # returns 100
Circumfator().get_circumference(50)  # returns 100
```

Comment: Note that these variables are effectively global as well: Each top-level ``class`` is ``global``, and it only owns one set of attributes. These attributes will have the exact same problem as "real" globals (shared by the entire process, no access control, ...).